# How to send array to subview and then print into label?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, subview

Working over storyboard.

I've created View Controller (storyboard) and then in middle of content added subview from xib file.

I want to add xib (UIView) like as subview into ViewController and send object with data and print that data into label but I don't know how.

Here is my code.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *subView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *subView; //connected over IB
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "OfferViewController.h"
#import "OfferLocation.h"

@interface OfferViewController ()

@end

@implementation OfferViewController

@synthesize subView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    OfferLocation *location = [[OfferLocation alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.subView addSubview:location];
}
...
@end
```

and here is subview:
**OfferLocation.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OfferLocation : UIView{
    UIView *view;
    UILabel *locationLabel;// here is that label taht I want to print into
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view;// connected over IB
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;

@end
```

**OfferLocation.m**

```
#import "OfferLocation.h"

@implementation OfferLocation

@synthesize view, locationLabel;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        locationLabel.text = @"some text"; //this is not working
        NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OfferLocation" owner:self options:nil];
        UIView *tempView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview:tempView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I've created instead of UIView, new UIVIewController (OfferLocation) and then edit just top of this new view controller and add as subview to middle of ViewController.h. Is that correct?
OfferLocation (UIVIewController) is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/77033905/subview%20ss.png
I'm using green part as subview.

Comment: That's not ok way, I figure it out correct way. In IB I just deleted deault view and added UIView from object library and now is everything ok. I somebody need's help over this problem feel free to ask and I will help.

Answer (score 0):

subView never seems to be initialized and loaded to the view or presented. Therefore you cannot see it.

Try calling:

```
            self.view = self.subView // or subView; // or [self.view addSubview:self.subView // or subview];
```

or something similiar

Then declare a UILabel and initialize it with whatever text you want and add it to subview:

```
         UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithString:@"StackOverflow rocks!"];
         [self.subView addSubview:label];
// or [self.view addSubview:label];
```

Differing on how you set subView.

What is this data you want to set on label's text? If it is a data type use the specifiers in the string.

```
        %i // for int
%@ // for string or object adress
%c // for char
%f // for float
```

etc...

Comment: subView I have created over IB and connected and it is working. Subview above is working but I don't know how to send array to subview and how to define text in label which I already created and connected over  IB

Comment: my code in first post is working everything except sending array to that subview which I don't know how to do and if you look in "OfferLocation.m" you will see line "locationLabel.text = @"some text"; //this is not working
". This label is created over IB and connected/synthesized but I can't set text to that label. This 2 problems I have. Tnx for helping mi out